# Remove parentheses for empty year field biblatex ieee style

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, ieee-style

By using biblatex ieee style, I found that the reference will display empty brackets even though the field "year" is undefined. How can I remove it without having to change the biblatex.bst?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\x.bib}
@ELECTRONIC{MEMSnet,
  title = {What is {MEMS}?},
  organization = {MEMSnet},
  url = {http://www.memsnet.org/mems/what_is.html},
  urldate = {Dec. 01, 2013}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\x.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I got

(). What is MEMS? MEMSnet, [Online]. Available: http://www.memsnet.org/mems/what_is.html.

which is not a correct citation style. I would like to have:

What is MEMS? MEMSnet, [Online]. Available: http://www.memsnet.org/mems/what_is.html.

Many Thanks

Comment: The demo for the IEEE seems to indicate a year is _required_: can you point to them publishing something without a year?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In `ieee.bbx` we find the lines

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{online}{%
  [...]
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  [...]
```

So `biblatex` tries to use the `date` macro (which actually just defaults to `\printdate`) and wrap its output into parentheses. If it does not print anything, well, then an empty string is wrapped into parentheses, resulting in what you got above.

The obvious cure is to provide the entry with a `date` field (after all, [almost] every bib entry should have one, see also Joseph Wright's comment above), this can be difficult and outright impossible with some `@online` resources though.

Since we do not want to rewrite the whole `@online` driver (an obvious way to fix the problem), we patch it using [`xpatch`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xpatch).

Load `\usepackage{xpatch}` and put this code into your preamble

```
\xpatchbibdriver{online}
  {\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}}
  {\iffieldundef{year}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}}}
  {}
  {\typeout{There was an error patching biblatex-ieee (specifically, ieee.bbx's @online driver)}}
```

It will replace the offending line discussed above (`\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}`) by a (more or less sophisticated) construction in which we check if there is a `year` field (i.e. a sufficient date field) and only if that condition is met (i.e. only if a year exists; here of course we presuppose that `year` is the bare minimum requirement for a date output in the bibliography) we go on to print the date, otherwise nothing is done.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ELECTRONIC{MEMSnet,
  title = {What is {MEMS}?},
  organization = {MEMSnet},
  url = {http://www.memsnet.org/mems/what_is.html},
  urldate = {2013-12-01},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\xpatchbibdriver{online}
  {\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}}
  {\iffieldundef{year}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}}}
  {}
  {\typeout{There was an error patching biblatex-ieee (specifically, ieee.bbx's @online driver)}}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{MEMSnet,wilde,markey}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Incidentally, it is never a bad idea to have an author and `biblatex` is not too indisposed to accept corporate authors. So one might go with `author = {{MEMSnet}}` here.

Comment: Also the `urldate` should have the format `yyyy-mm-dd`, so better use `urldate = {2013-12-01},`.

Comment: Is there a way to do something analogous with `style=alphabetic` and with the reference `@article`? I would need it for arxiv stuff, where the year is not listed.

Comment: @Stefano The modifications needed for `@article` in the standard styles (e.g. `alphabetic`) are vastly different, so I suggest you ask a new question.