# Remove fields for online entries in biblatex ieee style

Tags: biblatex, ieee-style

I'm writing a sitography with biblatex and I have this result:

[image]

I'd like to remove both the empty `()` and the `[Online]` field. I'm using the ieee style.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151264/190902 one can adjust the bibliography driver for online entries:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@online{test,
  author       = {Smith, S.},
  title        = {Title},
    url                  = {www.google.com}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  url         = \adddot\addspace Available ,
}


\DeclareBibliographyDriver{online}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
    \iffieldundef{year}
        {}
        {\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}}
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \printlist{language}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \printfield{version}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{url+urldate}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{related}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\begin{document}

\cite{test}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```