# Biblatex format: IEEE style

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, ieee-style

This is my first time working Biblatex, and bibliographies in Latex in general. I am writing a Math paper and would like to use the IEEE style. However, I am having a problem where there are empty brackets '()' in some citations. From what I've gathered, this problems seems to happen when the citation is referred to as `@online`. However, the sample.bib file was generated using Zotero and `@online` was chosen whenever a website was cited. I have shown a sample code with 2 citations where this problem occurs and one where it does not below. My hope is to be able to remove those brackets.

For reference, I am using Overleaf as the editor.

main.tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=ieee
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}

Test one \cite{brit_time_nodate}

Test two \cite{lynn_primality_nodate}

Test three \cite{nitaj_mathematical_nodate}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

sample.bib file:

```
@online{brit_time_nodate,
    title = {Time Complexity (Exploration)},
    url = {https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/time-complexity-exploration/1466763719},
    titleaddon = {Khan Academy},
    author = {Brit, Cruise},
    urldate = {2021-02-19},
    langid = {english},
}

@online{lynn_primality_nodate,
    title = {Primality Tests},
    url = {https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/numbertheory/millerrabin.html},
    titleaddon = {Stanford University},
    author = {Lynn, Ben},
    urldate = {2021-02-20},
}

@misc{nitaj_mathematical_nodate,
    title = {The Mathematical Cryptography of the {RSA} Cryptosystem},
    url = {http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.357.6080&rep=rep1&type=pdf},
    publisher = {Laboratoire De Mathématiques Nicolas Oresme},
    author = {Nitaj, Abderrahmane},
    langid = {english},
}
```

Output:

[image]

<strike>As a secondary question, what another citation style be suitable for a Mathematics paper? I would prefer to not use generic Latex styles but rather well-known standards (such as MLA, Chicago etc.) that is also suitable for Maths.</strike>

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I see no parentheses if I typeset the code you provided

Comment: When I typeset your document with a current version of `biblatex-ieee` (`2020/12/29 v1.3d`) I get the empty parentheses in a slightly different location (namely after the title). IEEE style simply assumes that all your entries have publishing dates. If you cannot find a `date`, then you can try the solution at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151217/35864.

Comment: The secondary question is probably more or less off-topic here. It might be more appropriate on https://academia.stackexchange.com/, but even there it might be considered opinion-based. Generally, journals and publishers have their own style guides that you need to follow when you want to publish there. For theses and other university work there might also be some university imposed styles. For other works the standard styles work well enough. It's really up to you. Have a look at what papers/books you like do. ...

Comment: ... I don't think I have ever seen a maths paper using MLA style. Chicago notes style would also be quite unusual. But many people like author-year citations, so I have no doubts that one might be able to find APA style or Chicago author-year style in some maths papers.

Comment: @moewe I appreciate your comments regarding the style but I agree with its lack of relevance here and have adjusted my question accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much for the referral to the other question, that did the trick! As you wrote it as a comment, can I accept it as an answer or do I just leave it there. (Sorry, new to using these forums as well)

Comment: If the linked Q&A resolved your issue, we can simply close your question as a duplicate. (I just did that.) That way we do not have to write the same answer multiple times across the site.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119979/discussion-between-kev-and-moewe).